# React hook saved state in Event Listener wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, event-listener, react-hooks

I have points and a function to update points:

```
const [points, setPoints] = useState([])

const updatePoint = (updatedPoint) => {
  setPoints(points.map(point => (point.id === updatedPoint.id ? updatedPoint : point)))
}
```

I've added a Listener to the marker:

```
window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend',
  function (markerLocal) {
    console.log(getPoints)       
  }
)
```

If I click on first marker after I've created it, it shows me 1 point in the console.
If I create and click second it shows me 2 points, So it saves the state inside of the listener. However, after the second save, the sum of points for the first marker doesn't change(when it gets dragged). Is this the right behaviour? How can I get two points for the first marker? Whenever I try to update my point list and click the 1st marker, it gives me only one point - that's wrong.

Comment: I think you may need to show more of your code - what is `getPoints`? Where are you setting up your listeners?

Answer (score 7):

Try adding useEffect with `points` dependency and set addEventListener for google maps. An issue here is the scope that the initial addEventListener is working on. In regular JS you would always have the current value in the scope, however, in hooks, your code will reference stale values from previous renders. In your case, you are referencing the values your `points` state was at the time of attaching the event to Google Maps. The cleanest solution here, in my opinion, is the Leftium's one, but you can also try this one for 'academic' purposes:

```
const onGoogleMapsMarkerDragend = () => {
    console.log(points);
}
useEffect(() => {
    const dragendListener = window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', onGoogleMapsMarkerDragend);
    return () => {
        window.google.maps.event.removeListener(dragendListener );
    }
}, [points];
```

Not sure if removeListener is valid - check with the documentation

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the handler uses the `points` at the time of declaration, which might be updated before it is invoked. My solution to such issues was to define it as a ref:

```
const points = useRef([]);
// This means that instead of `setPoints` you will do points.current = newValue

const updatePoint = (updatePoint) => {
   points.current = points.current.map(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If a previous state is used to calculate the new state, as in your example, you should pass `setPoints()` a function of the old state instead of the new value directly:

```
const updatePoint = (updatedPoint) => {
  setPoints((prevPoints) =>
      prevPoints.map(point => (point.id === updatedPoint.id ? updatedPoint : point)
  ))
}
```

Relevant section from Hooks API Reference: [Functional updates for useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)